# Is it right to say "a meeting is supervised by"?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

Assume that we have a meeting that will be managed by 3 people. We want to make an advertisement to let people know the people who will manage the meeting. What should we say?

> This meeting is supervised by Chico, Harpo, and Groucho.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "managed"? Usually, a meeting is ***chaired*** by a single individual, but it would be a bit odd to say *three* people chaired the meeting. I think perhaps ***hosted*** might be a better bet here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the meeting is called for an announcement or presentation, you can say the meeting is *presented by* the people giving the presentation.

If the three people are executing the agenda of a formal meeting, you can say the meeting is *chaired by* them, though a meeting with more than one chair is not practical. If they are simply requesting the meeting, it is *called by* them.

For less formal situations, where the participants discuss rather than deliberate, the meeting is *led by* or *facilitated by* the meeting leaders; they *run* or *lead* the meeting, rather than chair or preside over it.

In the U.S. at least, meetings in organizational settings are not usually *supervised* or *managed* unless the participants are children, as both words carry connotations of monitoring and oversight of untrustworthy or unruly participants. A teacher might supervise a meeting of teenagers, for example, to make sure the theme of the school dance they are planning is not offensive.

Comment: +1. Good answer. Although I'd point out that even in the US, supervised meetings can occur, for instance when the person leading the meeting is in training, and might need someone to quickly jump in and save the day if it all goes wrong.